# Separate XML line for debug or release mode in android manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-debug

My Android manifest uses different values when debugging and when releasing.

What's the easiest way to differentiate a value for each build type?

When debug:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my-lovely-debug-api-key" />
```

When release:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my-lovely-release-api-key" />
```

tia.

Comment: what build system are you using ? (maven, ant, gradle...)

Comment: whatever eclipse uses :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you are using default Eclipse builds it probably uses a specially configured 'Ant' module within eclipse. You can check on the degree of Eclipse/Ant coordination by checking 'Window/Preferences/Ant' section in eclipse/Prefs....

One solution is to make more explicit, the collaboration of Eclipse/Ant so that a 'build.xml' file is part of your project ( project level build file rather than the default file copied in at build time from the $SDK/ROOT folder ).

see [here](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html) and read the comments at bottom [here](https://github.com/jeremyhaberman/android-custom-builds/blob/master/build.xml) to get better idea of how a project level 'build.xml' file is used.

Once you've digested that , the solution below will make more sense...

**--Solution--**

Modify the Release and the Debug sections of you 'build.xml' file as follows:

```
  <!-- **************** Debug specific targets *************** -->
  ...
    <target name="-set-debug-mode" depends="-setup">
  ...

        <!-- API modify belo for build-typ -->
         <copy file="config/strings.xml" todir="res/values">
       <filterset>
    <filter token="CONFIG.API" value="${config.db.api}"/>
    <filter token="CONFIG.REST" value="${config.db.rest}"/> 
    </filterset> 
    </copy>
  ...



   <!-- *************** Release specific targets ************** -->
  ...
  <target name="-set-release-mode" depends="-set-mode-check">
   ...
   <!-- API modify belo for build-typ -->
   <copy file="config/strings.xml" todir="res/values">
     <filterset>
     <filter token="CONFIG.API" value="${config.db.api.prod}"/> 
     <filter token="CONFIG.REST" value="${config.db.rest.prod}"/>
    </filterset> 
   </copy>
```

And in the 'ant.properties' file in your root folder, put the property values for the API keys and whatever...

```
# API condition builds dev|prod in DB @parse.com
config.db.api=some_key_val
config.db.rest=some_k2_val
config.db.api.prod=some_k3_val
config.db.rest.prod=some_k4_val
```

And tie it together in a resource xml that is the target of the 'copy' commands in the build...

```
 'config/strings.xml'  

<string name="default_value_parse_key_appId">@CONFIG.API@</string>
<string name="default_value_parse_key_rest">@CONFIG.REST@</string>
```

Comment: seems better than my current solution which is code than runs pre-build to swap the values. thanks